# How do I decode a PEM-encoded PKIX public key?

Tags: go, pem

The example given in Go's [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/x509/#ParsePKIXPublicKey) for `x509.ParsePKIXPublicKey` encounters a runtime error because the `Block` that `pem.Decode()` returns is `nil`.
 ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/t4_FVpCQFj))

However, the example in the [official documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/pem/#Decode) for `pem.Decode()` runs just fine. ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/Hq8xIC6cRg))

The only difference I've spotted between the two examples is the the way the public key is initialized and they way it is used in `pem.Decode()`.

First example:

```
const pubPEM = `
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    ...
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`
block, _ := pem.Decode([]byte(pubPEM))
```

Second example:

```
var pubPEMData = []byte(`
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    ...
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----`)
block, rest := pem.Decode(pubPEMData)
```

I've edited the first example so that it is done in the same way as the second, but this did not change the outcome. ([Playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/WYgZ21qK_R))

**What is causing the first to fail but not the second?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have spaces in your string, remove them and it will work: [fixed example](https://play.golang.org/p/m32BfYEr85)

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how those spaces got added